# English translation of word in Kli Yakar Shemos 6:3

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, translation, pentateuch-chumash

וע"כ נקט ראיה, וידיעה בדרך לא זו אף זו, כי **הרעות** לא זו ידיעה אלא אפילו בראיה עין בעין נראה
להם, והרחמים גמורים לא זו שלא ראו אותם עדיין אלא אפילו לא נודעתי להם

[(Kli Yakar, Shemos 6:3)](https://www.sefaria.org/Exodus.6.3?ven=The_Koren_Jerusalem_Bible&vhe=Miqra_according_to_the_Masorah&lang=bi&with=Kli%20Yakar&lang2=en)

Trying to understand what this word (הרעות) means? It doesn't make sense to say "to do bad" as in the end of the last parasha. Does it mean "friendship" in this context?

Comment: In context, the same verb root can also mean “to associate with”, in the sense of thinking or assuming something about someone or something without actual evidence like from direct visual observation. That appears to be the message from the Kli Yakar snippet you have quoted.

Answer (score 1):

In the previous paragraph the Kli Yakar differentiates between "seeing" and "knowing", with the former being more definite and personal than the latter. He is saying that the Avos personally "saw" the bad side of life "הרעות" but not the redemption. Not only that but they did not even "know" the redemption.

So the term הרעות is just the plural of רע- bad- with the definite article in front. Compare to [Eicha 3:38](https://www.sefaria.org/Lamentations.3.38?ven=The_Koren_Jerusalem_Bible&vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&lang=bi)

> מִפִּ֤י עֶלְיוֹן֙ לֹ֣א תֵצֵ֔א **הָרָע֖וֹת** וְהַטּֽוֹב׃
> Out of the mouth of the most High do not both good and **evil** come?

It is a different word than the word at the end of Parshas Shemos, despite it having the same letters. (Confusing, I know.)